# How to download all images whose size>100kb in a webpage?

Tags: wget, curl

I want to download images contained in some web pages, but only those that are larger than 100 KB. So far I've been downloading all the images and then deleting the small ones, but it's not very efficient. Is there some way to ignore the small ones when downloading?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use a http HEAD request, only the headers will be returned.

Here's a sketchy approach (assuming you have a list of urls).
threshold=`expr 100 \* 1024`

```
for url in ${list_of_urls} ; do    
    size=`curl -s --head ${url} | grep 'Content-Length:' | cut -d ' ' -f 2` 

    if [ ${size} -gt ${threshold} ] ; then  
        curl -s ${url}
    fi    
done
```

Comment: It is unclear, how this is relevant to the problem of downloading images.

Comment: @rozcietrzewiacz That's apartial answer, showing how to determine which images match the length requirement and download them. The missing piece is parsing the web pages to gather the image URLs.